# Set a button group's width to 100% and make buttons equal width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, and I'd like to set an entire `btn-group` to have a width of 100% of its parent element. I'd also like the inner buttons to take equal widths. As it is, I can't achieve either.

I've made a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BcQZR/12/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="span8 background">
<div class="btn-group btn-block" id="colours">
<span class="btn"><input type='checkbox' name='size' value='red'/>red</span>
<span class="btn"><input type='checkbox' name='size' value='orange'/>orange</span>
<span class="btn"><input type='checkbox' name='size' value='yellow'/>yellow</span>
</div> <!-- /btn-group -->
</div>
```

And here is my current CSS, which doesn't work:

```
#colours { 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**BOOTSTRAP 2** ([source](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/))

The problem is that there is no width set on the buttons. Try this:

```
.btn {width:20%;}
```

**EDIT:**

By default the buttons take an auto width of its text length plus some padding, so I guess for your example it is probably more like 14.5% for 5 buttons (to compensate for the padding).

***Note:***

If you don't want to try and compensate for padding you can use `box-sizing:border-box;`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: Done! (just had to wait 5 mins till SO would let me accept.) Thanks again.

Comment: CHeck the css3-rule "flex"!

Comment: @andersoyvind Thanks for the info, however I am not totally sold on w3fools.com. I have used box-sizing:border-box; so I know it works and I know that the syntax / information listed on this particular page is accurate. Keep in mind any page documenting code is prone to error and the best way to see if it works is by testing it.

Comment: What if you don't know the number of buttons beforehand ?

Comment: @CDT, You could probably use flex now days. Assuming you don't have to support older versions of IE. OregonJeff has an example of flex in his answer.

Answer (score 158):

Bootstrap has the `.btn-group-justified` css class.

How it's structured is based on the type of tags you use.

[With `<a>` tags](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-%3Ca%3E-elements)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
   ...
</div>
```

[With `<button>` tags](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-<button>-elements)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: an example could be usefull.

Comment: It is important to point out that with using `.btn-group-justified` there is a difference on how you structure it based on either `<a>` and `<button>` tags http://getbootstrap.com/components/#with-<a>-elements

Comment: This should definitively be the accepted answer. Do you know why we need to wrap each `.btn` in a `.btn-group` ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks. 
when we modify width It definitely kills the responsiveness. This works perfect. :-)

Comment: I have used above <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="..."> for my two buttons width issue and its worked like a charm...thank you @Sam Axe

Comment: This option has been removed in Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/migration/#button-group

Answer (score 42):

There's no need for extra css the `.btn-group-justified` class does this.

You have to add this to the parent element and then wrap each btn element in a div with .btn-group like this

```
    <div class="form-group">

            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="like" class="btn btn-lg btn-success ">Like</button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="nope" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger ">Nope</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: This will split the buttons equally, if you want to have one button larger than the other, you need to set the width of each button: `<div class="btn-group" style="width: 80%">` `<div class="btn-group" style="width: 20%">` would give you an 80-20 split.

Answer (score 12):

I don't like the solution of settings widths on .btn because it assumes there'll always be the same number of items in the .btn-group. This is a faulty assumption and leads to bloated, presentation-specific CSS.

A better solution is to change how .btn-group with .btn-block and child .btn(s) are display. I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
.btn-group.btn-block {
    display: table;
}
.btn-group.btn-block > .btn {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DEwX8/123/

If you'd prefer to have equal-width buttons (within reason) and can support only browsers that support flexbox, try this instead:

```
.btn-group.btn-block {
    display: flex;
}
.btn-group.btn-block > .btn {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DEwX8/124/

Comment: Oh and second: For Bootstrap 3 use `.btn-group-justified`

Comment: This doesn't produce equal length for individual buttons. Anything to add?

Comment: @PiotrekZatorski, you're incorrect. The example I offered is using Bootstrap 2, but this updated version is using Bootstrap 3.3.6. http://jsfiddle.net/DEwX8/138/

Comment: @MalayDesai, my second fiddle absolutely produces equal width buttons (within reason). If you put an enormous amount of text in one and very little in the others, it obviously won't but for similar length button strings, they'll all be the same width. In the second fiddle, they're all 96px wide.

Answer (score 10):

For **bootstrap 4** just add this class:

`w-100`

Comment: Also add h-100 if one button in a row has wrapping text but another doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 4 removed .btn-group-justified. As a replacement you can use `<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group"></div>` as a wrapper around elements with .w-100.

Try this:

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is great, get the size of the buttons to adapt to the resolution of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

**Angular** *- equal width button group*

Assuming you have an array of 'things' in your scope...

- Make sure the parent div has a width of 100%.
- Use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to create the buttons within the button group.
- Use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) to calculate the width for each button.

---

```
<div class="btn-group"
     style="width: 100%;">
    <button ng-repeat="thing in things"
            class="btn btn-default"
            ng-style="{width: (100/things.length)+'%'}">
        {{thing}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group btn-block">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default btn-xs  btn-block  dropdown-toggle">Actions <span class="caret"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button><ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Action one</a></li><li class="divider"></li><li><a href="#" >Action Two</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4**

```
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Longer nav link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Code snippets should always come with some sort of explanation as to why that code works. Thanks!

Comment: Answered here for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190248/how-to-get-button-groups-that-span-the-full-width-of-a-parent-in-bootstrap Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4 Solution**

```
<div class="btn-group w-100">
    <button type="button" class="btn">One</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Two</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Three</button>
</div>
```

You basically tell the `btn-group` container to have width 100% by adding `w-100` class to it. The buttons inside will fill in the whole space automatically.