# How to get button groups that span the full width of a parent in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, buttongroup

In Bootstrap, how can I get a button group like the following that span the full width of a parent element? (like with the ".btn-block" class, but applied to a group http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes )

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly this [Justified button groups](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.btn-group.special {
  display: flex;
}

.special .btn {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group special" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: best method to use

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could; this works like a charm

Comment: For those using bootstrap 4.5 just use .d-flex along .btn-group

Answer (score 110):

Correct solution for **Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5** (from Bootstrap 4 migration documentation):

> Removed .btn-group-justified. As a replacement you can use `<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group"></div>` as a wrapper around elements with **`.w-100`**.

Example:

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default w-100">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default w-100">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default w-100">Right</button>
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#button-group

Edit: verified solution with Bootstrap 5

Comment: Works perfectly, simple, standard. Thanks.

Comment: Add class `w-100` to the `.btn-group` element, too.

Comment: for me it also works fine without adding `w-100` to each button class in `bootstrap 4.5.2`

Answer (score 7):

You can also use bootstraps `btn-block` will span across parent.

Create block level buttons—those that span the full width of a parent—by adding .`btn-block`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">Block level button</button>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 4, make use of `.d-flex` on your `.btn-group` and `.w-100` on individual buttons:

```
.btn-group.d-flex(role='group')
  button.w-100.btn.btn-lg.btn-success(type='button') 
  button.w-100.btn.btn-lg.btn-danger(type='button') 
  .btn-group(role='group')
    button#btnGroupDrop1.btn.btn-lg.btn-light.dropdown-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='dropdown')
      | &#8226;&#8226;&#8226;
    .dropdown-menu
      a.dropdown-item(href='#') An option
      a.dropdown-item(href='#') Another option
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `.btn-group-justified`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</a>
    <a href="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</a>
    <a href="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Outdated.
Removed .btn-group-justified. As a replacement you can use <div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group"></div> as a wrapper around elements with .w-100.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#button-group

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="btn-group btn-block" role="group">
    <button class="btn btn-success col-sm-10" type="submit">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger col-sm-2" type="submit">Button 2</button>
</div>
```